# Find overlap between two polygons

Tags: postgis

I have a two shapefiles, one is a [DMA](https://github.com/simzou/nielsen-dma) level and one of US [states](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2014/layers.cgi) level.

How do I create a shapefile containing DMA of a certain state, for instance, Texas from a larger shapefile.

I tried running this query, but with no success.

```
SELECT geom FROM usdma
WHERE ST_Overlaps(usdma.geom, usstates.geom)
WHERE usstates.name = 'TX';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   usdma.geom 
FROM 
    usdma,
    usstates
WHERE 
    ST_Overlaps(usdma.geom, usstates.geom) AND
    usstates.name = 'TX';
```

I'd rather go for ST_Intersects or ST_Within though.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the difference between ST_Within and ST_Intersects? My understand is that those two are used to count points, but I may be misunderstanding the functions?

Comment: Please see [the](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Within.html) [docs](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) :-)

Comment: @MinhMai you can also see ["spatial predicates" for the DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM#Spatial_predicates) to understand the language